# Adding a list of managed libraryDependencies (of an arbitrary length) within an SBT Build

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, sbt

In a nutshell, I have written a tool in scala that generates a list of jars from those stored in a directory locally, that parses a given repo identifying the groupID that matches each local jar and outputs all the necessary information to use in sbt. I want to be able to resolve a list of dependencies identified at runtime (otherwise this is useless) to essentially automate the update process when building more complicated applications for hadoop as well as to test program compatibility for different builds and conditions.

> Bottom Line: I have not found a solution which allows me to pass librarydependencies discovered within the build, to the build.

## Some Things I Have Tried:

1) Using keywords within for loops

I generated the jarList with a Dependencies.scala code in the /project directory and added this to my build.sbt

```
jarList.foreach(x => 
libraryDependencies += x.GroupID % x.ArtifactID % x.Revision
)
```

2) Manually editing the build.sbt by appending each libraryDependency found to a line at the bottom of the build.sbt file by running something like this in my /project/Dependencies.scala file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

try{
  val file =new File(new 
File(".").getAbsolutePath().toString.replaceAll("^(.*)\\.(.*)$","$1$2")++"build.sbt")
  if(!file.exists()){
    file.createNewFile()
                    }
  val fw = new FileWriter(file,true)
  val bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)
  val pw = new PrintWriter(bw)
  pw.println(s"""libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.7.3" """.stripMargin)
  pw.close();

  println("Data successfully appended at the end of file")
}catch {
  case ioe: IOException => println("Exception occurred:")
  ioe.printStackTrace()
}
```

This option sort of works (if I completely stop and restart the build)

3) Loading/running one sbt build before another build, the problem is that it seems like SBT always loads information from each build.sbt file resulting in the same problem as that above.

Has anyone else ever tried to do anything like this? Or does anyone have any ideas/ advice on doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What are you getting when you use `jarList.foreach(x => libraryDependencies += x.GroupID % x.ArtifactID % x.Revision)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can go with the first option, changing it a little bit.
In your `build.sbt` file declare a list of module ids produced from your `jarList`:

```
lazy val jarDependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = jarList.map(x => x.GroupID % x.ArtifactID % x.Revision)
```

Then add it to `libraryDependencies`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= jarDependencies
```

Remember that `build.sbt` contains pure Scala code, maybe with just few limitations (like having statements that result in `Unit`, e.g. calling `foreach`, is not allowed). So knowing the types of certain declarations (`libraryDependencies` has type `SettingKey[Seq[ModuleID]]`) should help with adding more magic.

Comment: Wow exactly what I needed, and kept simple. Gotta love that scala map function. Thank you for taking the time to respond (and clearly even test for yourself). I was at the point where I was creating a multi project build where project A would load first and run code to manually modify the code in project B.  http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Setting-Initialization.html